# Applying Windows-style Bulk Renaming Mechanism in MacOS

Tags: macos

For simple bulk renaming actions, which is what I do most of the time, I really like the way Windows does it - select a bunch files, press `CTRL+F2`, write the string, and all files are renamed to that string, followed by a serialized number enclosed in parenthesizes.

[image]

Is there ANY way to configure macOS to behave the same (but using macOS's default `↵` as the shortcut)? Paid 3rd party solutions are totally accepted.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The build in Finder application supports bulk renaming...

In Finder: Just select the files you want to rename, right click on them, then click rename...

Comment: I know, but it's very limited: (1) I believe it doesn't support RegEx, so I can't replace everything with a string. (2) I don't think it support renaming and serializing in the same go. (3) Finder's bulk renamer can't be invoked using a hotkey.

Comment: You can set up a hotkey In system preferences ...

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this? Where do I find this setting? Moreover, is there a way to configure a renaming pattern such as `DESIRED NAME`(`SERIALIZED NUMBERING`)?

Comment: http://appleinsider.com/articles/18/03/09/how-to-streamline-your-workflow-by-creating-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-in-macos-high-sierra hope this helps

Comment: I didn't manage to define `↵` as the shortcut that will invoke the rename menu. Moreover, I don't think the shortcuts preferences menu allows for defining of hotkeys that work only under certain conditions (in my cost, only when a few files are selected in Finder).

Comment: Bump. Is there any way to invoke this [this](https://i.imgur.com/rnPXdOP.png) command by pressing `↵` whenever there are two or more files selected in Finder? This would a great start in finding an ideal solution to my need, even without paying for a 3rd-party app. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I’ve been using the very powerful paid app A Better Finder Rename for many years.

You can find it [here](http://www.publicspace.net/ABetterFinderRename/).

Disclaimer: I’m an extremely satisfied user. No financial or other connection to PublicSpace.net.